# Convertir Date() en String

Tags: java

Quiero convertir el tipo `Long` que devuelve `new Date().getTimeInMillis()` a `String`

El siguiente código no funciona, **genera una hora diferente a mi zona horaria**

```
private String formatDate(Long fechaInTypeLong) {
  Date date = new Date(fechaInTypeLong);
  SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  return formato.format(date);
}
```

¿Cómo convertir en `String` de acuerdo a `UTC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para convertir un long a string, tienes varias opciones:

- Utilizar toString():

  new Date().getTimeInMillis().toString();
- Concatenar un string:

  (new Date().getTimeInMillis())+"";

Para solucionar el tema de que no te muestra la hora correcta, si es por la localización puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);      //En vez de ENGLISH pon el tuyo
```

Answer (score 2):

si usas .toString() te lo convierte al formato estandar, sino
proba con Format , por ej

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

o DateFormat

```
DateFormat fecha= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String aux= fechaHora.format(date);
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta, ya que mi codigo lo convierte en otra hora, creo que es por la zona horaria

Answer (score 2):

Intenta esto:

```
return formato.format(date).toString()
```